# Collections while iterating through enumerator

Tags: c#, .net

When running this code:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "foo",
    "bar",
};

foreach (var l in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(l);

    list.Add("bar");
}
```

An exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

How does .NET know that the collection is modified while enumerator is iterating that collection? Is there a flag for this in the collection object?

Comment: *How C# compiler knows* compiler does **not** know this fact, as it's a run-time detail, not a compile-time one :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `List<T>` internally holds its "version" in an integer variable. Each modification to the list (Add, Remove, Sort, Clear, ...) increments this version by one.

Now the enumerator for a `List<T>`, when initialized, saves this version number. Upon every `MoveNext()`, i.e. on every iteration, it checks whether the list's version number still equals the saved version number.

This way it can detect when a list is modified between two iterations. Note this implementation causes a peculiar bug with integer overflow: [Why this code throws 'Collection was modified', but when I iterate something before it, it doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718990/why-this-code-throws-collection-was-modified-but-when-i-iterate-something-bef).

There also appears to be a bug regarding `Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)`, which doesn't increment the version number. This code:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "foo",
    "bar",
};

foreach (var l in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(l);
    list.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
}
```

Prints:

```
foo
foo
```

Comment: And of course it was a [duplicate](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/8071), @Thomas. :P

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the typical solution is a flag, version value etc., e.g. in case of `List<T>`

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

it's a version

```
 private int _version;
```

E.g.

```
 public bool MoveNext() {
   ...
   return MoveNextRare()
 } 

 private bool MoveNextRare()
 {                
   if (version != list._version) {
     ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
 }
```